# CCSprite with rounded corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this code:

```
CCSprite * monster = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:_imgInimigo.image.CGImage key:@"inimigo"];
```

I want to add rounded corner in this CCSprite. Its possible? How?

Comment: Have you considered just taking the current image, rounding it with an image editor, or something of the like?

Comment: Are you looking to clip the `monster`, if so you can use `CCClippingNode`? Otherwise, can you add a before and after image of what you are looking for?